# How to play mp4 at normal speed on jupyter notebook using python opencv

Tags: python, opencv, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

Are there any ways I can play mp4 videos with the same speed as the actual file on jupyter notebook using python opencv?
When I make .py file and use cv2.imshow() then the speed is normal, but when I try the code below on jupyter notebook, it gets very slow.
My code:

```
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from IPython import display
%matplotlib inline

cap = cv2.VideoCapture('video.mp4')

while(cap.isOpened()):
    try:
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        plt.imshow(frame)

        display.clear_output(wait=True)
        display.display(plt.gcf())

    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        cap.release()
```

Answer (score 1):

In my experience it's better to use OpenCV's display functions even if you work in Jupyter notebook. This can be achieved like this:

```py
fps = 30
title = 'normal speed video'
delay = int(1000 / fps)

for frame in frames(video):
    cv2.imshow(title, frame)

    if cv2.waitKey(delay) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Here `frames` generator simply yields video frame by frame and can be [found here](https://gist.github.com/vladislav-goncharenko/d9e1fef1ee40fa36f610acebeabbcc25)

---

Also a video can be displayed in Jupyter programmatically via `Video`:

```py
from IPython.display import Video

Video(‘https://archive.org/download/Sita_Sings_the_Blues/Sita_Sings_the_Blues_small.mp4’)
Video(‘path/to/video.mp4’)
Video(‘path/to/video.mp4’, embed=True)
Video(b’raw-videodata’, embed=True)
```

[See docs](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/generated/IPython.display.html#IPython.display.Video) for more info